# Why is my Flask app login page/template not updating?

Tags: python, html, flask, django-templates, pycharm

My Flask app is rendering an old template from like a month ago. It was just a barebones login form.
Now I have a much better login form that was loading fine until a week ago. I have spent the last week trying to get it back to loading my current files. Even removing the render template statement in my /login route and replacing it with "please" doesn't work. I am at a loss. Please help.

See code:

In auth.py:

```
authPages = Blueprint('authPages', __name__, template_folder='templates/auth')


@authPages.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    return "please" #render_template('auth/login.html', COMPANY_NAME=COMPANY_NAME, SOFTWARE_NAME=SOFTWARE_NAME)
```

And then **main**.py:

```
from flaskr.auth import authPages
from flaskr.interface import interfacePages
from flaskr.GLOBAL_VALUES import app

app.register_blueprint(authPages)
app.register_blueprint(interfacePages)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Project Structure:

[image]

interfacePages doesn't have a duplicate /login.

I searched through all of my project files using PyCharm find function and couldn't find another /login route.

Expected HTML:

please

Actual HTML:

[image]

Comment: have you imported auth.py., can you post structure of the folder. is there any error if you remove render_template .

Comment: A wild try. Try deleting the browseer cache and cookie data.

Comment: @charchit updated Q with project structure.

Comment: You have to keep python files out of template folder.

Comment: @charchit there are no py files in templates. they are under flaskr

Comment: But in your image i see it is same level that of other folder in templates. Please recheck.

Comment: @charchit it's on the same level as templates. the file icons are lined up with template folder. upon collapsing the templates folder. the py files are outside.

Comment: I think I should run the files on my machine, if you don't mind , can you share the code like github or discord `charchit#8198`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `app.run(debug=True)` to automatically load the page every time you save the main.py file.
Or use ctrl+f5 to hard refresh the webpage.

Comment: The bug is replicated in debug mode. It still loads the old HTML page (from a month ago).